# How to localize JQUERY UI Date Picker in Orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, orchardcms

is there any way in orchard to localize date picker according to site culture?
any help is where appreciated.

Comment: It already is. Can you give more details about the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: i have changed site culture to persian.but datepicker is still showing default calendar.is there any way to explicitly set the datepicker culture?

Comment: i suspect that maybe i have to specify site culture somewhere in translation(po) files.is it true?

Comment: you don't have to specify culture, but you need a complete set of po files that cover the translation of that particular bit.

Comment: where did this po files have been placed?

Comment: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-global-ready-applications#Installingtranslationfiles

Comment: i have already downloaded these files.i wanna know which one is specific to datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean JQuery date picker then you should ruther look into Orchard module called Orchard.JQuery there you should place your `ui.datepicker-<language>.js` file into Scripts folder and it should start working.