# orchard cms built in datetime field

Tags: datetime, content-management-system, field, orchardcms

How can i plug my date time field in place of built in one?
I want to change date time field repository type from datetime to string not just for my modules but also for all wxisting fields like page creation date time.

Comment: If storage data type could not change then how can i replae just the formatting way of built in date time field from input to storage field?

Comment: Let me explain more, if i define my datetiem filed how can remove default built in one and then place my new one in all module?

Comment: someone say than can add script [link](file:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949117/how-to-localize-jquery-ui-date-picker-in-orchard) but does not work.

Comment: I have to ask: why why why would you want to do that?

Comment: because calender localiztion for persian is not just translating texts, but also changing calendar logic in client side jquery ui calendar and also in binding that's not supported now by .Net framework.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "in bindings that's not supported by .net framework": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx Also, for jQuery, this looks like a better solution: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx I really don't see how any of this requires not storing dates as dates. A point in time is a point in time. Calendars are visualizations of moments in time.

Comment: Thanks. Now how can i enable this jquery globalization plugin for my client in Orchard? when i set the culture, calendar remains as en-us culture.

Comment: In Orchard.JQuery module in DatePickerLocalization.cshtml the calendar (logic) property of datepicker not changed by culture, how can i say jquery to change it in orchard?

Comment: this article describe my problem well: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32096/How-to-Set-PersianCalendar-to-CultureInfo) : .NET Framework doesn't support Persian calendar for the culture. This culture doesn't accept the calendar; therefore display of DateTime in this culture is impossible.

Comment: I see. Still, it doesn't seem to me like the solution is to modify the storage as what is stored should just be a standard date. I would build a shape table provider that modifies the date shape on the fly to add the scripts that you need.

Comment: You are right, changing the storage not a good solution. The solution i think is to change two type of places , all place in code that input is converted to date time and apply persian logic in convertion if current culture is FA, second in  DatePickerLocalization.cshtml that the farsi date picker should be enabled in FA culture and this requires appending fa date picker script.

Comment: sounds like a good plan.