# orchard cms - overriding date field shapes

Tags: datetime, orchardcms, globalization, shapes

For some problem in globalization(
[orchard cms built in datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989905/orchard-cms-built-in-datetime-field))
,I need to change datetime related shapes in all existing modules, the shapes includes (I think):

- Parts.Common.Date.Edit.cshtml
- DateTimeRelative
- DateTime

How can I change all of these shapes in all existing module?
The changes are: adding some script to editor and some special formatting in other two shapes.
And finally if I changes the above three shapes, then all date related input and display in all place in orchard site would be changed?
I read lots of articles for doing this but i can't understand well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be that those shapes are mostly in the admin. One thing you can do is take a dependency on the module defining them (in module.txt) so that your templates can take precedence. But changing the shapes probably won't be enough and you'll probably have to get your own driver in there to fix the dates on the way back. That being a little trickier, what I would probably do is handle all the locale-specific stuff in script on the client-side and send back to the server a date that has already been converted back to Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Thanks @bertrand, I want to do that you say. I change it in client side before sending it back to server. How can i change the shapes? I can't understand it well!

Comment: First Q:I should change all existing modules.txt files and add name of my module (MyCultureClientAdaptor) to dependecy list of them?

Comment: Second Q:How can I redefine three named shaps?

Comment: You change the shapes by overriding them in the views folder of your module: create files with the same name but in your module. No, don't change any code outside of your module. It's in *your* module.txt that you need to declare the other module as your dependency.

Comment: Thanks @bertrand very mush,but now first Q is that two shape of above list are method not template so i can't reimplement them in template but in shape method i can. second Q is that if I define dependency in my module to all ot them , the date shapes in them would be changed? For Example in date shape in PublishLater would be changed?

Comment: You can override a shape method with a template of the same name.
Yes, declare dependencies on all modules on which you want to do overrides.

Comment: Thanks @bertrand, is it possible to override shape with shape method not template? how?

Comment: So how can I override DateTimeRelative in my module?

Comment: The solution work well, but what can I do for model validation messages? The date in messages are non localized.

Comment: Look for validation attributes with names starting with "Localized" (they are in Orchard.Mvc.DataAnnotations)

Comment: The problem is the way invalid date time is formatted into string, I'm implemented a module that override date time shape, so the date field display specialized in client side but sent to server in goregian format, so i want to change the way date formatted into validation message.

Comment: The **{0}** in this: T("{0} is an invalid date and time").

Comment: Maybe you can just replace it with a more generic string that says "The data and time are invalid"? Without the {0}.